# Rudin finite and countable Definition 2.4

Tags: elementary-set-theory

With reference to Baby Rudin Definitions 2.4, - Are finite sets not countable? He defines finite sets as equivalent to Jn and countable sets as equivalent to J - where J is the set of ALL positive integers

Comment: Some authors use the term countable for countably infinite.

Comment: Thanks... Understood...